# Фильтрация "плохих" символов в php

Tags: php, фильтры, безопасность

Здравствуйте, разбирая код популярных движков постоянно встречаю функции вроде "remove_bad_characters", содержимое которых сводится к удалению символов вроде \0... Скажите, насколько важна подобная фильтрация и критична ли она с точки зрения безопасности? Заранее огромное спасибо!
Вопрос не по теме - код какого движка лучше разобрать чтобы понять "как делать правильно" (структура, фильтрации и т.п.)

Comment: Бери и делай, опыт придет со временем. Тебе никто не сможет передать чувства очередного взлома. Защитить всё и сразу невозможно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\0... - это восьмеричное число, и это не значит что оно плохое, есть совсем другие недобрые литералы. Не нужно рыться в движках чтобы понять, что нужно удалять. В движках роются те люди, у которых достаточно опыта / знаний, и роются они в других целях.

По поводу критичности. Да, некоторые символы критичны для безопасности, и их нужно фильтровать. Но для того чтобы их фильтровать придёться многому научиться. Для начала стоит хорошо выучить язык на котором вы учитесь программировать / кодить и воспользоваться его базовыми функциями для фильтрации данных.

Критичные моментов много, если не понимать принципов создания приложений и их безопасности.
Этому можно и научиться и ощущать логику кода самому. Но читать и учиться нужно всегда.

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос не имеет смысла вне контекста. Увидели подобное - посмотрите на окружение, поймите в каком контексте это делается, зачем, какие именно символы удаляются и из каких данных (что с ними делается потом), и т.д. А вместо вас разбираться в потрохах какого-то движка и пытаться понять вырванную из контекста мелочь в нём просто не интересно, по крайней мере до тех пор, пока она не станет критичной для применения вот этого, отдельно взятого, движка  :)

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения безопасности - абсолютно бесполезно и слишком накладно по ресурсам.

Подобные функции имеют смысл при записи в базу данных, там это оправдано.

В основном эти функции рассчитаны на удаление всех плохо выглядящих символов т.к. они ломают разметку сайта (не всегда).

Возможно я вас неправильно понял, если это произошло - уточните вопрос.

Comment: Причём здесь разметка? Разговор идёт о PHP. И что значит с точки зрения безопасности абсолютно бесполезно? Через input взломать базу нельзя если не фильтровать? Или через url? Или загон строковых данных в числовой тип столбца?
Извините, но Вы написали бред.

Comment: Приведите пример осмысленной фильтрации. Именно фильтрации, с удалением "плохих" символов.

Comment: GenchiK, я не понял ни содержание вашего ответа ни комментария - учитесь излагать свои мысли.

klopp, например фильтр кавычек при отправке запроса в базу данных.

Comment: @Сергей, юзерские данные - священны :) Если они прошли валидацию, то должны быть сохранены as-is. Их можно преобразовывать с разными целями, но все эти преобразования должны быть либо обратимы, либо не затрагивать сохранённые оригиналы. Кавычки тут вообще непонятно при чём, учитесь работать с БД, а не удаляйте неудобные лично вам символы :)

Comment: 2 человека не умеющих читать... Передохните, сходите погулять и если найдете время перечитайте еще раз.

Comment: Перечитал. Менее бредовой эта мысль не стала: "В основном эти функции рассчитаны на удаление всех плохо выглядящих символов т.к. они ломают разметку сайта (не всегда)"

Comment: В вопросе сказано что такие функции встречаются, где же не описано, поэтому я предположил самое логичное - в выводе.

Comment: Хе :) Самое "гениальное", что встречалось - замена "не a-z" на подчёркивание в именах фотоальбомов. Потому что они создавались как каталоги на диске, и этим умникам показалось, то так будет надёжней. Сами же имена при этом хранились в базе, и привязывались к каталогам вида "____2011______" (Май 2011, Рига). Называлась функция, которая эту хрень делала, само собой, remove_bad_characters. Воистину, сон разума рождает чудовищ :-)